# eclipse rcp progress monitor

Tags: java, progress-bar, eclipse-rcp, jobs

I am using Job class to create some task and I am using the progress monitor to show the progress in the progress view.

```
    Job createNewJobRun(final int i, final Job previousJob) {
    Job job = new Job("Test Job " + i) {
        @Override
        protected IStatus run(IProgressMonitor monitor) {
            monitor.beginTask("Job is running", 100); //$NON-NLS-1$

            if (previousJob != null) {
                try {
                    previousJob.join();

                } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
                            // do the real work 
            monitor.done();
            return Status.OK_STATUS;
        }
    };

    job.schedule();
    return job;

}
```

I don't want to run the jobs in paraller but sequentially,how can I initialize the jobs in the progress view to show that the will execute after the previous is finished.
The code above justs wait for the previous one so its blocking after the second job and no progress bars are shown...

Answer (score 3):

The Scheduling Rule should look like:

```
   public class MutexRule implements ISchedulingRule {
      public boolean isConflicting(ISchedulingRule rule) {
         return rule == this;
      }
      public boolean contains(ISchedulingRule rule) {
         return rule == this;
      }
   }
```

setting the Rules and scheduling:

```
   Job job1 = new SampleJob();
   Job job2 = new SampleJob();
   MutexRule rule = new MutexRule();
   job1.setRule(rule);
   job2.setRule(rule);
   job1.schedule();
   job2.schedule()
```

Source: [Eclipse Wiki: FAQ How do I prevent two jobs from running at the same time?](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_prevent_two_jobs_from_running_at_the_same_time?)

Answer (score 2):

You need to look at scheduling rules on Eclipse Jobs.

This should help.
http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Concurrency/jobs-api.html

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution is to use scheduling rules as proposed by @TomSeidel and @SambiReddy, but this solution have a number of limitations.

Especially, it only works so far as you don't schedule multiple new jobs before the all previous jobs have finished, as the scheduling rules normally used have no concept of sequence. This can be fixed, though the result is normally quite difficult to maintain.

You don't write anything about the jobs in question, but if we are talking about repeating the same job over and over again, then the simple solution is to re-schedule the job (just) before it is finished.

```
Job job = new Job("Test Job " + i) {
    @Override
    protected IStatus run(IProgressMonitor monitor) {
        monitor.beginTask("Job is running", 100); //$NON-NLS-1$

                        // do the real work 
        monitor.done();

        schedule(...);
        return Status.OK_STATUS;
    }
};

job.schedule();
```